# Storing JSON in Redis where several data items are optional

Tags: javascript, json, redis

I need to store the data in Redis in the following structure.

```
{
  "userId":1,
  "latitude":44.24,
  "longitude":-100.24,
  "items": [
    {
      "name":"Rollerball Pen",
      "attributes":[
        {"Weight":"10 grams"},
        {"Manufacturer":"Luxor"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"Measuring Tape"
    }
  ]

},
{
  "userId":2,
  "items": [
    {
      "name":"Laptop",
      "attributes":[
        {"Brand":"DELL"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"Scissor"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "userId":3,
  "latitude":47.24,
  "longitude":-102.37
},
{
  "userId":4
}
```

The key is the user id, probably like this:

```
"user:" + userId.toString()
```

Note that following are optional:
a. Latitude and Longitude
b. array of items
c. array of attributes (in items)

I have tried to sum up every possible use case using the 4 different user ids.

How can I store and access this kind of data in Redis, kindly help me out. The language that I am using is JavaScript.

Comment: Have you tried anything or encountered a problem? Or is this just a general question about how to model data like this in a NoSQL database? You might want to do some reading on NoSQL theory, and how you can use normalization and/or denormalization to optimize based on your needs.

Comment: NoSQL db is not at all involved. I have a in-memory data and i need to store it in Redis and then retrieve it at a later point in time.

This is not a general question but a requirement that I have to accomplish in a real-world project.

Comment: Yes, Redis is an type of in-memory NoSQL database known as a key/value store.

Comment: Can you share some examples of queries you will need to make against Redis? There are many ways to model data in this type of database, and the one you choose should depend on what you need to optimize for.

Comment: I am using Redis for the first time. I really don't know exactly which Redis commands shall I use to write this code.

Comment: First figure out how you plan to model your data. It will be obvious which commands to use from there.

Comment: How are you calling redis from javascript?  Once you have a connection, just call set  https://redis.io/commands/set

Comment: I have decided to go another route and not using Redis anymore. Thank you all for spending time on this question.